# Apply Additional Discount after coupon

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to provide special discount on cart items but want to apply right after the coupon OR when proceed to checkout is clicked.

**Example:**

The customer added an item in cart with total price $100 and he applied the coupon e.g `10%OFF`. Now the total remaining cost is $90 and now I want to apply additional 30% discount which will be on remaining cost ($90).

I found this but it does partial job:

```
function custom_wc_add_fee() {
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fee', -10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_wc_add_fee' );
```

First, it applies when the cart page is loaded. (whenever I need after coupon). Secondly, I'm unable to get the cart price so unable to apply percent discount. 
What I like about hook is that it adds a little description so customer knows what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your current theme function.php file. Set how many discount as per your require.

```
function add_extra_discount( $cart ) {

  $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.3;

  $cart->add_fee( __( 'Extra Discount', 'twentyseventeen' ) , -$discount );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_extra_discount' );
```